# Suggesting to lint a code before submitting

Tags: feature-request

There needs to be a way to display a pre-submit language-specific message with a strong recommendation to lint code.

For example, in languages like Python conventions are very important, and there are community agreed-upon norms and tools. When user submits code which does not follow conventions, reviewer spends extra effort on correcting simple style errors which user was unaware of.

Comment: Ruslan probably has [this question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/46328/1) in mind, where the author originally posted the code with leading tabs instead of spaces as required by Markdown.

Comment: @200_success: I do wish there was an easier way to solve that.  Not only would that make it easier on editors, but it'll avoid indentation reviews where the OP has actually used the correct indentation.

Comment: @200_success Not just that, but also every other question I answered. There's a lot of overhead with correcting small PEP8 (mandatory python convention) errors. One message to the user when user tags a question with `python` can resolve the issue completely.